# Object as TreeView.Nodes.Add argument?

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I was using a `CheckedListBox` to display a `List` of `Plugin`. And i'm using an `EventHandler` :

```
private void myCheckedListBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myGUIUtilities.SetDescription(myCheckedListBox.SelectedItem, myRichTextBox);
}
```

To display something ...
This is the `myGUIUtilities.SetDescription` method :

```
internal static void SetDescription(object p_SelectedObject, RichTextBox p_TextBoxDescription)
            {
                AbstractEnvChecker l_Plugin = p_SelectedObject as AbstractEnvChecker;
                if (l_Plugin != null)
                    p_TextBoxDescription.Text = l_Plugin.Description;
            }
```

To display my Plugins I just used the `CheckedListBox.Items.Add` method :

`MyCheckedListBox.Items.Add(myPlugin);`

That accepts an object as argument ...

Now i want to classify my `Plugins` by cetgories, so i'm using `TreeView` and `TreeNode`.

The problem is that the `TreeView.Nodes.Add(TreeNode node)` accepts only `TreeNode` Type as argument.

And i can't actually use the same `SetDescription` method which needs a `Plugin` Type to get the `Plugin.Description` Property ...

Is there a way to pass an object to the `TreeView.Nodes.Add(TreeNode node)` method ?
Or another way to do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Tag`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenode.tag.aspx) property on the tree node to attach an object to it.  Then you can pull it back out again later.

So you could do this (assuming a `Name` property on the plugin object)

```
public TreeNode AddPluginNode(TreeNode parent, AbstractEnvChecker plugin)
{
  TreeNode created = new TreeNode(plugin.Name) { Tag = plugin };
  parent.Nodes.Add(created);
  return created;
}
```

And then you can rewrite the start of your event handler thus:

```
AbstractEnvChecker l_Plugin = p_SelectedObject as AbstractEnvChecker;
if(l_Plugin == null)
{
  TreeNode selNode = p_SelectedObject as TreeNode;
  if(selNode != null && selNode.Tag != null)
    l_Plugin = selNode.Tag as AbstractEnvChecker;
}
//might still be null in the future if you start using Tags for other types.
```

Comment: The first part worked : `Tag = Plugin` . But the `l_plugin` is still null ... The variable `p_SelectedObject` is a simple `String` not an object ...

Comment: I suggest using the [NodeMouseClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick.aspx) event to handle when the node is clicked - grab the node from the [TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treenodemouseclickeventargs.aspx) that are passed and then pass it to your `SetDescription` method

Comment: I tried, but still `null` :


`void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender,  
    TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    GUIUtilities.SetDescription(((TreeView)sender).SelectedNode, this.richTextBox1);

}`

Comment: And here is the `SetDescription` method as you suggested :

`internal static void SetDescription(object p_SelectedObject, RichTextBox p_TextBoxDescription)
        {
            AbstractEnvChecker l_Plugin = p_SelectedObject as AbstractEnvChecker;
            if (l_Plugin == null)
            {
                TreeNode selNode = p_SelectedObject as TreeNode;
                if (selNode != null && selNode.Tag != null)
                    l_Plugin = selNode.Tag as AbstractEnvChecker;
            }
        }`

Comment: use `e.Node` in the event handler

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own tree node class that inherits TreeNode. Your inherited class can have a strongly typed reference to the plugin instead of using the tag property. I use this method for a fairly complex treeview with different kinds of objects, custom context menus, etc.